# Template comparison changes inside template body

Tags: templates, metaprogramming, d

I have a struct `Foo!T` and a function that operates on any two `Foo!T`.
I would expect such a function to be declared

```d
void fun(U)(U a, U b) if (is(U : Foo!T, T...)) { }
```

However, it turns out that I can declare it as

```d
void fun(U)(U a, U b) if (is(U : Foo)) { }
```

*only if* I declare it *inside* the body of `Foo`.

For example:

```d
struct Foo(T) { 
    void fun1(U)(U b) if (is(U : Foo)) { } 
}

void fun2(U)(U a, U b) if (is(U : Foo)) { }

unittest {
    Foo!int f;
    f.fun1(f);
    f.fun2(f);
}
```

The above fails with `struct d.Foo(T) is used as a type` on the invocation of
`fun2`. `fun1`, however, is fine.

Why is the constraint `is(U : Foo)` valid inside the body of `Foo`, but not
outside?

Is the comparison `is(U : Foo)` inside the body of `Foo` equivalent to `is(U :
Foo!V, V...)` outside the body of `Foo`?

Comment: This kinda smells like a bug, but it might be a strange eponymous thing too... Foo inside the Foo!T is expanding to be Foo!T (try `pragma(msg, Foo)` inside. On the outside, there is no instantiation. So they are NOT the same: inside Foo!int, it would accept other Foo!ints, but your fun2 would also accept Foo!string and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of a templated type, the name of the template refers to that particular instantiation of the template except when it's explicitly given a different instantiation. For instance,

```d
struct Foo(T)
{
    pragma(msg, Foo.stringof);
}
pragma(msg, Foo.stringof);

void main()
{
    Foo!int foo1;
    Foo!string foo2;
}
```

prints

```
Foo(T)
Foo!int
Foo!string
```

The first pragma printed is the one right after the template, and the other two are generated when `Foo` is instantiated. This makes it so that you don't have to plaster `Foo!T` all over the place inside your struct declaration when you're referring to it (e.g. when returning it from a member function). This is particularly useful if the type has several template parameters instead of just one. But it *does* mean that if you want to refer to the general template, you either need to instantiate it with specific arguments - e.g. use `Foo!int` inside of `Foo` to refer to `Foo!int` regardless of what the current instantiaton is - or you need to use the dot operator to indicate that you want `Foo` from the outer scope. e.g.

```d
struct Foo(T)
{
    pragma(msg, Foo.stringof);
    pragma(msg, .Foo.stringof);
}
pragma(msg, Foo.stringof);

void main()
{
    Foo!int foo1;
    Foo!string foo2;
}
```

prints

```
Foo(T)
Foo!int
Foo(T)
Foo!string
Foo(T)
```

So, when writing stuff like template constraints inside of a templated type, be aware that using `Foo` inside of `struct Foo(T)` or `class Foo(T)` will mean that specific instantiation and *not* the template itself.

Also, if you're looking specifically to test whether `U` is an instantition of `Foo`, I'd suggest using [`std.traits.isInstanceOf`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#isInstanceOf) - e.g. `if(isInstanceOf(Foo, U))`. Arguably, it really should be `isInstantiationOf` rather than `isInstanceOf`, but regardless, it does the job in a more idiomatic way than using naked `is` expressions.

Comment: Where is this defined in the spec? I figured it was true but couldn't prove if it was intended or not.

Comment: I took a quick glance at the spec, and I don't see it. So, my guess is that it's not actually officially documented. It's been that way for ages though, and often the spec is missing details like that. :|

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, a template like

```
struct Foo(T) {}
```

expands to the equivalent

```
template Foo(T)
{
    struct Foo {}
}
```

Raw template references automatically forward to a member in the template with the same name as the template:

```
Foo!int foo;
// expands to:
Foo!(int).Foo foo;
```

You can use this to make "hidden" template members that you need for some reason. `std.typecons.Tuple` uses this technique, for instance: it defines a number of helper templates and functions inside the `Tuple` template and then defines the `Tuple` struct. But you can use it as if it were just a templated struct.